# INSERT Trigger : UPDATE after INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Here is my trigger :

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[bf_insert_tt_personnel_a_creer] ON [dbo].[TT_Personnel_A_Creer]
FOR INSERT
AS
    BEGIN
        -- Déclaration des constantes 
        DECLARE @usr        VARCHAR(6) = 'DSI';
        DECLARE @adr_id     INT = 2;
        DECLARE @per_Image  VARBINARY(MAX) = 0x0;
        DECLARE @tyba_Id    INTEGER = 2;
        DECLARE @date       DATE = (SELECT GETDATE() -1);

        -- Declaration des variables de travail
        DECLARE @per_Id INT;
        DECLARE @bdg_Id INT;

        -- Récupération des informations de l'enregistrement
        DECLARE @src            VARCHAR(3)      = (SELECT src FROM inserted);
        DECLARE @matricule      VARCHAR(8)      = (SELECT matricule FROM inserted);
        DECLARE @nom            VARCHAR(50)     = (SELECT nom FROM inserted);
        DECLARE @nom_matr       VARCHAR(50)     = (SELECT nom_patronymique FROM inserted);
        DECLARE @prenom         VARCHAR(50)     = (SELECT prenom FROM inserted);
        DECLARE @date_naissance DATE            = (SELECT date_naissance FROM inserted);
        DECLARE @email          VARCHAR(200)    = (SELECT email FROM inserted);
        DECLARE @sexe           INT             = (SELECT case when (SELECT sexe FROM inserted) = 'M' then 1 else 2 end);

    
        -- Création de la fiche Personne (et Entite) via la procédure stockée prévue pour ça. On récupère le per_Id.
        EXEC @per_Id = [dbo].[createPersonne]
                            @per_Nom = @nom,
                            @per_Prenom = @prenom,
                            @per_Nom_Matr = @prenom,
                            @per_Url = '',
                            @per_Ddn = @date_naissance,
                            @per_Mob = '',
                            @cvt_Id = @sexe,
                            @catpax_Id = 2,
                            @per_Mail = @email,
                            @usr_Login = @usr,
                            @per_Mail_NPAI = 1,
                            @per_Mail_Desab = 1,
                            @per_Societe = '',
                            @adrId = @adr_id,
                            @macroEntChef = 0,
                            @per_Image = @per_Image;

        

        -- Ajout du matricule sur la fiche en question
        UPDATE 
            Personne 
        SET
            per_matricule = case @src when 'PE5' then @matricule else per_matricule end,
            per_Id_Rh_Externe = case @src when 'RHE' then @matricule else per_Id_Rh_Externe end
        WHERE
            per_Id = @per_Id;


        -- Récupération de l'ent_Id pour la création du badge
        DECLARE @ent_Id INT = (SELECT ent_Id FROM Entite WHERE per_Id = @per_Id);
        SELECT @ent_Id


    END;
```

As you can see, first I call a stored procedure. It creates a record in Personne, then another in Entite. These tables are joined by Personne.per_Id = Entite.per_Id.

The stored procedure 'createPersonne' returns me the per_Id of the inserted record in Personne.
Then, I want to UPDATE Personne and get the ent_Id (from Entite).

But when I trigger this trigger, I get a NULL ent_Id and the UPDATE on Personne didn't work. I tried to use GO after calling the stored procedure but I got a syntax error.

If I execute the script (not in the trigger) with a GO, I get my ent_Id.

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong and how to solve this ?
Thanks a lot <3

Comment: You have this error , because you don't set @per_Id inside your trigger ,  you only execute procedure  , show your  :createPersonne code what is inside

Comment: Your trigger is fatally flawed; it assumes a `INSERT` only ever contains one row; that is simply not true. [Bad Habits to Kick : Abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers), [The Silent Bug I Find in Most Triggers](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/) The above logic, however, should not be in an `TRIGGER` in my opinion. Calling a procedure in a `TRIGGER` is very likely going to be a (large) performance hit. Triggers should be as minimal as possible.

Comment: I would personally suggest you have the data you need to process going into a "pooling" table, and then have a scheduled task to consume that data in a **set-based** manner (your procedure is not currently set based, as it will only consume 1 set of scalar values).

Comment: @Adamszsz I set per_Id when I call the stored procedure. This part works well.

Comment: @Larnu This is the 1st time I try to use triggers ^^' Thanks for your advices. I'll try to apply them.

Comment: This trigger is broken in so many ways: Not taking account of multiple or zero rows. An `insert` followed by an `update` on the same row. Not using joins. What is the final `SELECT @ent_Id` supposed to do? I suggest you go back to the beginning and rethink the whole thing, what are you *actually* trying to achieve and why?

Comment: We need to see the [dbo].[createPersonne] procedure to know what it's supposed to return.  Your code implies the proc returns a return code.  If it doesn't then @per_Id would equal 0 when the proc executes correctly

Comment: As I said, the dbo.createPersonne works well and returns exactly what I want. Then, I see no reason to show it.
It creates a record in table Personne, and anothjer in table Entite. Tables are linked by per_Id (1-1). 

About the SELECT ent_Id, I did it just to be sure I get a NULL instead of the ent_Id created by the procedure.

If I call the procedure, then GO, then SELECT, I get my ID. But I can't use GO in a trigger.